# Constructing a monthly option from quarterly options and monthly futures

Tags: options, futures, hedging, delta-hedging

Say we have quarterly options and monthly futures where the strike price is based on the average price of spot during the corresponding period. There are no monthly options.

Can I effectively construct a monthly option by buying the quarterly option and selling the other months in futures?